# Question about inhomogeneous linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a feeling there is a trick to this question, but I do not know what it is.. Please help :)

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu23S.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\gamma:= \alpha +i \beta= \pi e^{i \frac{5}{7} \pi}.$

Observe that the constant function $1$ is a special solution of the inhomogenous equation. Thus

$h$ is a solution of the inhomogenous equation $ \iff h-1$ is a solution of the homogenous equation $ \iff \gamma $ is a root of the charactristic polynomial of the homogenous equation $\iff \sum_{k=0}^6 (-1)^k \gamma^k=0.$

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for the quick response.